# integral with respect to difference of two non-negative measures

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, probability-distributions, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Given that we have two finite non-negative measures $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$. Is the following always true?
$$\int_A f d\mu_1-\int_A f d\mu_2=\int_A f d(\mu_1-\mu_2)$$
I am already aware that when we have an addition the equality does hold true. What are other conditions that could make the equality hold/fail?

Comment: For finite measures, this is true (given appropriate conditions on $f$ of course... eg $f\in L^1(\mu_1)\cap L^1(\mu_2)$, in which case $f\in L^1(\mu_1-\mu_2)$, and the equality holds). You can also take $\mu_1,\mu_2$ to be complex measures (so necessarily finite-valued, and in fact having bounded range).